# Json casting to Dictionary

Tags: c#, json

I'm not 100% familiar with json and have looked around to see if my question has been answered yet, but anyway I have a json file that contains multiple dictionaries with this format:

```json
        {
            "String": {
                "string1": [
                    {
                        "level": 1,
                        "desc": "d1",
                        "icon": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "string2": [
                    {
                        "level": 2,
                        "desc": "d2",
                        "icon": "2"
                    }
                ],
                "string3": [
                    {
                        "level": 3,
                        "desc": "d3",
                        "icon": "3"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
```

String is static, but whereas the string1-3 are dynamic and can have any string value, multiple of these dictionaries appear throughout the file, running this through any of the json2class converters gives me Object String { get; set; }.

What I'm trying to do is to convert this to something along the lines of:

```C#
Dictionary<string, Object> Dictionary { get; set; }
```

```C#
public class Object
{
  public int level { get; set; }
  public string desc { get; set; }
  public string icon { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: post your convert code as well. From what I can see now you probably want to use dynamic/dictionary instead of Object.

Comment: Convert Code? StageBase = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StageBase>(json);

Answer (score 2):

You can easily deserialize you json string using [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) like this:

```
public class DictionaryContainer
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<SampleObject>>  String { get; set; }
}

public class SampleObject
{
    public int level { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}

string jsonString = "Your json string";
var dic =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DictionaryContainer>(jsonString);
```

Comment: When trying to do this, the var dic is null, any ideas?

Comment: `string _string = _Stage.Bosses.ToString();
Boss _Boss = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Boss>(_string);`

Code I'm using to Deserialize it

Comment: What is Boss? If you want to deserialize the jason you posted you should use 'Dictionary'. Could you please post your object definitions?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k42z658rvygflyn/get_stage.txt?dl=0 thats the json file, might be easier if you can see it.